# How to use Pager Layout in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to have different image on different page in HorizontalPager. How to do that

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = 3)
HorizontalPager(
    state = pagerState,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
  ) {
     Image(painter = painterResource(image1), contentDescription = null)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HorizontalPager` `content` is called for each page, you can get page index from the lambda argument:

```kotlin
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = 3)
HorizontalPager(
    state = pagerState,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) { page ->
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(
            when(page) {
                0 -> R.drawable.my_image1
                1 -> R.drawable.my_image2
                2 -> R.drawable.my_image3
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("image not provided for page $page")
            }
        ), contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

Comment: I added the HorizontalPager in my app but it’s not working on swiping to left or right because I added pagerstate in coroutine which scope.launch {page = pagerstate.currentpage} whenever I increment the pagercount then it works fine but on swiping left/right, it takes to first page

Comment: @RahulMatte please create a question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's hard to help you with this description

Comment: ok I will do it and tag you. HorizontalPager is experimental api and I am thinking if it is good to include in my production app? Because it will removed in future

Comment: @RahulMatte Experimental status means that API can be slightly changed in future, also it may be moved from Accompanist library to main Compose part, but it's not gonna be removed. I believe it's totally safe, just may need a little bit code updates after dependencies updating.